# Simplest way to show a clock in C++ and Linux

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, time, clock

I'm using C++ under Linux compiling with standard GCC. In my program I want to add a simple clock showing HH:MM:SS. What's the easiest way to do that?

Comment: use std::time(0) and then convert the number of seconds passed since 1970 Jan 1 to HH:MM:SS :)))) Just kidding

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good way is to use [localtime](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/localtime/)

Answer (score 5):

You can make use of [localtime](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/localtime/) along with [strftime](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/strftime/).

[**Working link**](http://www.ideone.com/GlPW0)

Answer (score 1):

My quick-and-dirty solution:

```
// file now.cc
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    time_t ct = time(0);
    struct tm* currtime = localtime(&ct);
    cout << setfill('0') << setw(2) << currtime->tm_hour << ":"
         << setw(2) << currtime->tm_min << ":"
         << setw(2) << currtime->tm_sec << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This also does zero-padding (which you probably want).

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
void delay(unsigned int mseconds)
{
    clock_t goal = mseconds + clock();
    while (goal > clock());
}
int main()
{
    time_t myTime;

    while(1)
    {
        time(&myTime);
        printf("%s", asctime(gmtime(&myTime)));
        delay(1000);
        system("cls");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What package is that `cls` command in?  I don't have it, in a fairly typical Debian installation.

Comment: cls is simply clear, calling clear if you're on linux does the job

Answer (score 0):

The *easiest* way?

```
system("date +%T");
```

Answer (score 0):

[Look at `getTimeStamp()`](https://github.com/gioragutt/training/blob/master/LogWriterClass/LogWriterClass/Sources/Logger.cpp#L123) you can adjust this to any format you want